# How to put max length on a field using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've got a working function for empty fields already. Do I need another function to set a max length on these fields or can I edit my current function?
If so how would I fit the max length code in?

Comment: Set `maxlength` at `html`

Comment: Your existing code cannot possibly work. The commas in your `if` condition do not do what you think they do.

Comment: If i HAD to use JavaScript... would I make a new function or edit the current one?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi please explain?

Comment: Explain what? How `if` works? How booleans work? How the comma operator works?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it does work, because if one field is empty it returns false. It only returns true when all fields are filled...

Comment: @dafyddgj Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). FrédéricHamidi meant that comma in `IF` statements (`|| a=="",b==null ||`) separates condition into a statement and condition: first part is a statement (in your case `a==""` just assign a new value to a variable), and the second part is a condition (`b==null`).

Comment: here is an example of what @neoselcev linked to : http://jsfiddle.net/7kep8ae9/ ; only the last part of your comma-separated expression will be taken into account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use JavaScript to do HTML's job.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" required maxlength="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional and prettier way to check for all fields. It assumes all field have the same validity requirement.

```
var maxLength = 8; // or whatever you want
var fieldNames = ["fname","sname","houseno", "ad1", "city", "postcode", "mobno"];
var invalidFields = fieldNames.find(function(fieldName) {
    var val = document.getElementById(fieldName).value;
    return val == null || val.length == 0 || val.length > maxLength;
});
if (invalidFields.length) {
    alert("Please fill ALL Required Fields (no more than " + maxLength + " chars)");
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Would I need to type - var val = document.getElementById(fieldName).value; for each field??

Comment: @Aaron didn't you forgot to assign a `maxLength` variable?

Comment: @dafyddgj  No, you have a `fieldNames` array for this, that'll include all you `input` fields ids.

Comment: @neoselcev I added it for clarity

Comment: @dafyddgj you might not be familiar with loops? here the `Array.prototype.find` executes its callback function for each fieldName, retrieving the field's value then checking nullity and size conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need another function for the max-length. I assume your validateForm method is called at the time of submitting the form. The max-length should be set before submitting the form, preferably when the page loads. As already stated in the comments, setting max-length via the HTML attribute will be the easiest way to do this. Otherwise you need to run a javascript function when the DOM has loaded that basically sets the maxlength attribute for each element, like a.setAttribute('maxlength', '10').